# Save as "Save and continue" vs Done as "Save and exit"

Tags: save, edit, flow

**Current workflow**:

- User clicks to edit a page
- User edits some stuff and clicks "Done"
- User automatically navigates to "Changes successfully published"

Our users want to be able to save changes and continue editing, without going to the "success screen", so that's what I've done:

- User clicks to edit a page
- User edits some stuff and clicks "Save"
- After a delay "Save" button changes to "Done"
- User clicks "Done"
- User automatically navigates to "Changes successfully published"

Things to consider:

- We cannot use "Publish" instead of "Done", because previously users were concerned about it.
- We cannot auto-save due to technical limitations

Here is the[image] screenshot

Comment: Why... 'After a delay "Save" button changes to "Done"' ?? ...and not a SAVE button *and* a DONE button?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles the reason is that I'm worried about having 3 blue buttons in a row "Save / Preview / Done" and make a user focusing more. From the other perspective I'm worried that a user will click "done" without reading

Comment: "Our users want to be able to save changes and continue editing..." Do you know how long they need to edit? Or how many times editing the form they'd like to "SAVE" and continue editing?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles from what I know it's completely random and depends on the type of the person, we heard feedback that users just want to save some part of the progress because they worry to loose it because of internet loss or other issues.

Some users do a lot of changes or spending much time loading new media content.

So yeah, auto-save would help a lot here, but technically we cannot do it right now.

+ I guess that's a good question to gather some insights on that.

Answer (score 0):

> ...users want to be able to save changes and continue editing...what I've done:
>
> - User clicks to edit a page
> - User edits some stuff and clicks "Save"
> - After a delay "Save" button changes to "Done"
> - User clicks "Done"
> - User automatically navigates to "Changes successfully published"

There's two problematic scenarios with this approach:

1. The user makes edits and is done. The user clicks "SAVE". Waits. Clicks "DONE" and leaves edit page.
2. The user makes edits, is not done but wishes to save edits. Clicks "SAVE" and continues to edit. The user again is not done but wishes to save. Clicks "DONE" and leaves edit page.

From comments...

> I'm worried about having 3 blue buttons in a row "Save / Preview / Done" and make a user focusing more. From the other perspective I'm worried that a user will click "done" without reading

SAVE and DONE having different background/foreground colors helps distinguish one from the other. DONE being the darkest gives it the sense of anchor, or finality. SAVE being a button helps it stand out:

[image: add save button]

However, another option is to style SAVE similar to PREVIEW, because neither of these two actions leave the form.

[image: add save link]

The user quickly learns PREVIEW and SAVE are in-edit actions, and DONE is terminal.